# Tabs not working in Single Page Application with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I have a "edit" view where I need to display tabs to separate the different information needed.  I found a site where it discusses the creation of a directive to catch the tab changing.  This is my first directive and it is not working.  When I click on the second tab, it takes me back to my default view.  Not sure what I have implemented incorrectly.

Web Page -

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a showTab="" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a showTab="" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a showTab="" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a showTab="" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>HOME</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 3</h3>
        <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The associated directive -

```
'use strict';

define(['app'], function (app) {

    var injectParams = ['showtab'];

    var wcTabDirective = function (showtab) {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(element).tabs('show');
                });
            }
        }
    };

    wcTabDirective.$inject = injectParams;

    app.directive('wcTab', wcTabDirective);

});
```

I have put a break point in the directive but it is never reached.

Comment: You don't seem like using `wc-tab` which sets up the tab. Also there are better ways to use [bootstrap with angular](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs)

Comment: @PSL ... this looks to be also a great way to implement this.  Just have to figure out how to display the different html files based on the selected tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually applied your "wc-tab" directive to any elements.

Try adding the directive to your tab anchor elements:

```
<a wc-tab showTab="" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
```

Check that the `showTab` attribute is correct as well. If it is a directive then it should be applied as `show-tab=""`.